# Rebuild SystemUIServer's database

Tags: macos, database

I'm not completely sure what happened, but in Console I get the following errors repeating endlessly every few minutes:

```
28/07/2013 12:32:10.009 SystemUIServer[304]: Unknown error finalizing or resetting statement (11: database disk image is malformed)
28/07/2013 12:32:10.009 SystemUIServer[304]: DB Query: begin exclusive transaction
28/07/2013 12:32:10.018 SystemUIServer[304]: Error calling sqlite3_step (1: cannot commit - no transaction is active) SQLITE_ERROR
28/07/2013 12:32:10.019 SystemUIServer[304]: DB Query: commit transaction
28/07/2013 12:32:10.019 SystemUIServer[304]: Unknown error finalizing or resetting statement (1: cannot commit - no transaction is active)
28/07/2013 12:32:10.019 SystemUIServer[304]: DB Query: commit transaction
```

It seems like some database that SystemUIServer uses has become corrupted, and I'm looking for a way to repair it or, more likely, force it to be re-created. I've had a little poke around in `/private/var/db` but I haven't seen anything that looks likely, and of course the last thing I want to do is try moving/deleting things at random as I'm pretty much guaranteed to make things worse :)

Currently the errors don't seem to interfere with anything, but I figure if this database is corrupt then I should really fix it if I can. At the very least so it stops filling my console with thousands of message a day!

Comment: The Database is called SQLite. Did you search for SQLite in your Library? As example I have one that is a part of a game (Solitaire).

Comment: If you make a second user account and log out of all accounts and then log into the newly created account - do you see any of these errors when only the new account is created? I'm skeptical that it's a sqlite issue since SystemUIServer doesn't directly open / write to any database files even though it uses DB queries to read other sources of data. Trying to track it down that way will require some advanced debugging and perhaps tracing some low level filesystem calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you got iStat Menus 4 installed? [This](http://www.mactechnews.de/forum/discussion/SystemUIServer-meldet-staendig-defekte-SQLite3-Fehler-in-Logs-312133.html) thread identified the iStat Menus network module as the cause of the problem. [Another one](http://www.macuser.de/forum/f21/sqlite-error-662316/) blames the CPU module.

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.

Comment: There's nothing more to say. Both links contain similar log messages and the solution: disable iStat Menus 4. Version 3 does not seem to cause this problem.

Comment: The idea is that future visitors don't have to follow a link (which may be broken by then) but can solve the problem based on information available directly in the answer text. That's why we prefer to have self-standing answers.

Comment: Aha, I do have iStat Menus 4 installed. In that case it sounds like the problem may be with one of iStat Menus' databases, and the error is mistakenly appearing as a SystemUIServer problem; if SystemUIServer is responsible for menubar widgets then that could explain the misplaced errors. I'll ask around at their own website and update here with what I find.

Answer (score 0):

**Step one: Information and Location**
Once we have found the databse(s) then we can go about fixing it.

It might be that one of the SQLite databases has become corrupted.

It is difficult to say which one from the information provided by you.

The SQLite comes with your Operating System.

*SQLite is a compact, cross platform, self-contained relational database management system that is available in the public domain. SQLite is include in Mac OS X. It is located in /usr/bin directory and called sqlite3.
Using SQLite, users can create file-based databases that can be transported across machines, platforms, etc. The only thing needed to then view or edit these databases is the SQLite command line program, or another tool capable of communicating with SQLite.
SQLite databases can be created by using the sqlite3 program in /usr/bin. To get to this program, you can open up a terminal windows (Applications -> Utilities -> Terminal) and then typing the following:*

```
cd /usr/bin/

sqlite3
```

You can exit the command line program by holding the control button and type z.

*You do not have to do this, it is for information only: Creating and editing databases is cumbersome using the command line program, so a graphical tool like [RazorSQL](http://www.razorsql.com/download.html) that is capable of communicating with SQLite makes it much easier to manage your SQLite databases.*

You can search for Databases in use on your computer using spotlight (.)sqlite.

This assumes you do not have a Virus (or better check for it) that has damaged your SQLite3.app

Answer (score 0):

Could be iStat 4, goto folder `/Users/account_name/Library/Application Support/iStat Menus/databases`
Move all files into the Trash and restart iStat/Computer ... should be magic.